# Cut off parameter from redirect in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

This silent redirect in htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pic_id=(\d+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^album_showpage\.php$ /gallery/image_page.php?image_id=%1 [L]
```

redirect a url that looks like:

```
example.com/album_showpage.php?pic_id=1906
```

to:

```
example.com/gallery/image_page.php?image_id=1906
```

that works great. But when the URL has a parameter like:

```
album_showpage.php?pic_id=1906&mode=prev
```

or

```
album_showpage.php?pic_id=1906&mode=next
```

the redirect wont work.

Question: How to cut of any parameter after pic_id=1906

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need match against the rest of the query string.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pic_id=(\d+)(&.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^album_showpage\.php$ /gallery/image_page.php?image_id=%1%2 [L]
```

If you don't want the `mode=prev` stuff to be included in the rule's target, then you can simply remove the `$` instead of attempting to match against it:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pic_id=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^album_showpage\.php$ /gallery/image_page.php?image_id=%1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer after 35 seconds. Awesome. I tried the first anwser with QSA too (doenst work ;) )   With this second try the redirect dont work also. It opens the page but it doestn hit the gallery/image_page.... do you have a other idea how to cut of this paramater or better all?

Comment: works perfect now. Was my fault. I purged the browsercache but I have to purge the CDN also. Now it works perfect. Thank you Jon Lin.